# How to generate PWM using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am using the Python codes to generate PWM signal in using vectorization method.But still facing issues.Could anyone help me in this.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

percent=input('Enter the percentage:');
TimePeriod=input('Enter the time period:');
Cycles=input('Enter the number of cycles:');

y=1;

x=np.linspace(0,Cycles*TimePeriod,0.01);
t=(percent/100)*TimePeriod;

for n in range(0,Cycles):
    y[(n*TimePeriod < x) & (x < n*TimePeriod+t)] = 1;
    y[(n*TimePeriod+t < x)& (x < (n+1)*TimePeriod)] = 0;

    plt.plot(y)
    plt.grid()
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vectorized solution :

```
percent=30.0
TimePeriod=1.0
Cycles=10
dt=0.01 

t=np.arange(0,Cycles*TimePeriod,dt); 
pwm= t%TimePeriod<TimePeriod*percent/100 
plot(t,pwm)
```

[image]

Above speed (100x than loop version here), from [numpy docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/whatisnumpy.html) :

> - vectorized code is more concise and easier to read
> - fewer lines of code generally means fewer bugs
> - the code more closely resembles standard mathematical notation (making it easier, typically, to correctly code mathematical constructs)

Comment: This looks impressive, but gave me a flatline on the graph. Could you explain how it works?

Comment: I don't know why. t%T is a saw signal between 0 and 1.`pwm` is  a boolean array which is True (1) 30% of the time.

Comment: Ty, got it. I'm using Python 2.7 and forgot the line 'from __future__ import division' so I got integer division. Brilliant solution.

Comment: @B.M.: I am getting a flat line on graph since pwm is showing false and moreover %matplotlib inline is giving syntax error.I am using Python 2.7.6.

Comment: I edited my post, defining percent and TimePeriod as float for python 2 compatibility. Sorry for that. %matplotlib can be replaced by from pylab import *

Comment: @B.M:This is the smartest answer.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest issue was that you can't assign to y[index] unless y is a vector, but you made it a number. Now there are many ways to do that periodic assignment, I personally like to use the `modulo` `%` operator.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

percent=float(raw_input('on percentage:'))
TimePeriod=float(raw_input('time period:'))
Cycles=int(raw_input('number of cycles:'))
dt=0.01  # 0.01 appears to be your time resolution

x=np.arange(0,Cycles*TimePeriod,dt);  #linspace's third argument is number of samples, not step

y=np.zeros_like(x)   # makes array of zeros of the same length as x
npts=TimePeriod/dt

i=0
while i*dt< Cycles*TimePeriod:
    if (i % npts)/npts < percent/100.0:
        y[i]=1
    i=i+1

plt.plot(x,y,'.-')
plt.ylim([-.1,1.1])
```

[image]